# Javascript not working when adding another script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok Guys please forgive my ignorance. I'm new to javascript so all help is well received. I've been trying to implement these solutions but it's not working. This is what I have on my revised code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict() // return `$` to it's previous "owner"
    (function($){ // in here you're assured that `$ == jQuery`
    $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#slider1').tinycarousel()
    $('a.fancybox').fancybox()
    $('textarea, select').uniform()
    $('#slider').nivoSlider ({ pauseTime: 6000, effect: 'sliceDown'})
    })
    })(jQuery)
    </script>
```

When i do this it makes all of the above stop working.

Also, I still have the other statement

```
    function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Which Im not sure if I understand what to do with it since if I take it off the element that goes with it stops working (it's a dual slider)

Thanks Again

---

I'm a javascript novice so my apologies :0)

I'm using this javascript on a website:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#slider1').tinycarousel();
        $('a.fancybox').fancybox();
        $('textarea, select').uniform();
        $('#slider').nivoSlider ({ pauseTime: 6000, effect: 'sliceDown'});
    });
    </script>
```

There is another script that contains this at the beginning which is making everything else to stop working. As soon as I delete it everything works again. Is there a way to unite these? or do they need to stay separate?

```
    function $(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to "shield" your code from this kind of problem by never using the `$` function directly, instead create a new scope where you explicitly define `$ = jQuery`:

```
jQuery.noConflict() // return `$` to it's previous "owner"
(function($){ // in here you're assured that `$ == jQuery`
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#slider1').tinycarousel()
        $('a.fancybox').fancybox()
        $('textarea, select').uniform()
        $('#slider').nivoSlider ({ pauseTime: 6000, effect: 'sliceDown'})
    })
})(jQuery)
```

Alternatively, jQuery passes itself to the DOMReady short form:

```
jQuery.noConflict()

jQuery(function($){
        $('#slider1').tinycarousel()
        $('a.fancybox').fancybox()
        $('textarea, select').uniform()
        $('#slider').nivoSlider ({ pauseTime: 6000, effect: 'sliceDown'})
})
```

Make this a standard practice and you'll avoid the issue in the future.

Comment: Thanks again everyone for all the answers They are really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to release `$` and the use `jQuery()` instead of `$()` for jQuery operations:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    // Now $('x') uses the custom $ function.
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have declared a function called $ which now overwrites the jquery reference that is created by jquery.

thus when you do `$('#slider1').tinycarousel();` you are now expecting a method `tinycarousel` defined on the object returned by your function.

if you still want to continue using jquery and your function you will have to use

```
jQuery("something").tinycarousel()
```

Comment: also add $.noConflict(); as suggested by mu so that you explicitly remove the $ reference that query creates.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably remove the second script because jQuery itself contains ID selector which will select elements from dom using id as requirement.

#### Remove this

```
function $(id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

#### Do this from now to select with ID

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#myCarousel").fadeIn();

});
```

Comment: That might render the entire second script useless though, and it might be as long and complicated as jQuery is for all we know. However, jQuery has the dollar-safe options (don't remember how it's done, but it's pretty simple).

Comment: LOL ... why is his script overwriting JQuery? Anyway, this should fix the problem. If you are including the jquery in the header of your webpage (ie <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>).

Comment: @Alxandr no point in reinventing the ID selector u agree? also jQuery would provide chainability. `#script2` would not

Comment: your not addressing the question you are giving a suggestion which could be in a comment.

Comment: @Baz1nga OP `Is there a way to unite these? or do they need to stay separate?`. Yes it is already united in jQuery. u get it?

Comment: @Deeptechtons I'm not saying you should reinvent the ID-selector, but say you downloaded 2 scripts from the big old internet, jQuery, and another script that solved a problem you needed solved on your page. Only, that other script used $ to get an element by it's id (like for instance mootools). Then you can't expect a por fella that's new to javascript to go trough that and change the $ everywhere, or rewrite the library to jQuery as your answer implies.

Comment: Thank you guys for the super fast responses. This is going a little over my head but let me see if I can figure it out with all of your answers. Thanks a bunch again!!!

Comment: the function `$(id)` from script#2 returns a DOM element.  jQuery's `$(...)` function returns a jQuery set object.  These are not the same things, so you can't replace script#2's `$` function with jQuery's `$` function.

Comment: anyway Heads up for the downvote, i don't care. If someone cares explain the downvote. Does it not answer the question? Does it not solve the problem? Is it not working? Is it way off topic?

Comment: It does not work, and therefore does not solve the problem.  See my comment above for details about this.

Comment: @Lee thanks for explaining the downvote. Appreciate it great comment